# Custom Twitter Login in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, twitter-oauth

I'm going to implement one application, in that i want to integrate twitter.

Here is the Details of this particular task.

1. When application starts it will display the login(this is not twitter oAuth authentication login, this is normal login functionality using the WSDL web services)
2. When ever user login successfully the tweets will display in the next page.(without enter any login credentials using twitter oAuth).

Can anyone please help in this?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you could set up your own server which will receive the log in credentials from your device and use them to log in to Twitter. All the role would be played by the server i.e. to log in, fetch the feeds and then send you the tweets.

But this would not be doable without getting XAuth permission from Twitter. For this, you have to drop an e-mail to them explaining why you need to have XAuth implemented in your application.

Good luck!